# How to copy Unity Game (SpaceFlight Simulator) from Galaxy S6 Edge to S9?

Tags: backup, samsung-galaxy-s

I have been looking for a way to transfer game progress of Space Flight Simulator (made by Unity) from a Galaxy S6 Edge to a new Galaxy S9. Please note that /data/data/ directory does not exist on both devices, there is no PlayerPrefs folder, I can't root the S9 as it's still new and under warranty (so can't use TitaniumBackup) and the game isn't connected to an online server (no Google Play Account). I copied whatever files related to the game I found on the S6 Edge (all under Internal storage/Android/data/) to the S9 but it didn't work. I have also tried Helium Sync and Backup (free version) but it seems that it creates backups to be restored on the same device, not a different one.

I have been looking for a way for about 2 weeks now, but haven't found naything. The game developer isn't sure where saved data is stored on the S6. I have also looked in this forum and couldn't find anything useful. Is there any way that doesn't involve writing code (I'm not a programmer), rooting any of the devices or buying paid apps?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Summarizing from the comments on the question:</sup>

Helium *does* do the job if the actions are performed correctly:

1. Backing up the app on the source device
2. on the target device, copy the folder to the exact location to where Helium creates the backups
3. on the target device, restore the app.

If step #2 wasn't exactly followed, *Helium* wouldn't find the backups on the target device.

A comparable approach would be using [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) [backup](/questions/tagged/backup) (see our [ADB tag wiki](/tags/adb/info) for details). To use that, you will need to know the *package name* of the app to deal with (that is e.g. what you find on the playstore URL by the "id" parameter). Then:

1. Connect the source device
2. Run `adb backup -f foobar.ab -apk com.app.foobar`¹
3. Disconnect the source device, connect the target device
4. Run `adb restore foobar.ab`¹

Another detail: you can mix the two approaches. Backups created by Helium contain that `*.ab` file, which you could pass to `adb restore`.

---

¹ <sub>of course replace `foobar` and `com.app.foobar` with the corresponding app name</sub>